# Does Rubymine have the feature code snippet and all auto-complete

Tags: rubymine, rubymine-7

I'm used to the sublime  text 3 editor.

It has many handy features.

take the code snippets for example,

Once you type `begin` then press TAB

It will generate the corresponding code block

```
begin

rescue Exception => e

end
```

And the plugin [All Autocomplete](https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete)

It can show the auto-complete hint for all opened files.

For example, if you have a variable name called **`taiwan_is_awesome`**

then you can get the autocomplete in other files.

Does Rubymine has the above features ?

If yes, what's the corresponding keymap ?

It's important for me to use those features.

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once you type `begin` then press TAB

It's called **"Live Templates"**.

*"Live templates (or code snippets) allow you to insert frequently-used constructions into your code. These can be conditions, blocks, loops, and so on."*

You can manage bundled and create new ones at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Live Templates`.

Here is a good "how to use" tutorial with screenshots: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm -- it's for PhpStorm but exactly the same functionality is available in RubyMine.

---

**UPDATE: 2022-11-15**
The above tutorial link now automatically redirects to the corresponding Help page for PhpStorm.

Here is the same official Help page but for RubyMine that shows how to use and create them: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/using-live-templates.html

Answer (score 1):

The setting you want to make RubyMine code completion work like [All Autocomplete](https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete) in Atom & ST3 is called "Autopopup code completion".

### Solution:

#### Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion > "Autopopup code completion"

[image: RubyMine Code Completion settings]

Note: there is another type of code completion called "Hippie Completion".
However, it works differently than "All Autocomplete". In RubyMine "Hippy Completion", you start typing text, and then you have to "guess" when RubyMine has enough text to figure out the completion you want. Then you hit ⌥/ (on the Mac). If RubyMine guesses right, it will autocomplete correctly.

I greatly prefer the "All autocomplete"/"Autopopup code completion" method, but just thought I'd mention this alternative.

Comment: This doesn't work like All Autocomplete, even if you press hotkey it can't find anything and writes "No suggestions"